# Semantic UI Not Building CSS

Tags: gulp, less, semantic-ui

I have setup Semantic UI in a Laravel application using gulp/bower/composer/npm.  Semantic UI is in /resources/semantic/, which has the Semantic gulp file and /dist/ /src/ and /themes/.  When I run gulp build, everything finishes properly, no errors, the JS is compiled into /dist/semantic.js and semantic.min.js, and there is supposed to be /dist/semantic.css and semantic.min.css.  However no matter what I do, I can't get it to build the CSS.  I have used Semantic before on other projects without any issues like this.

Has anybody else run into this problem? I read that it could be a problem with Node versions, so I installed the latest and still have the issue.

Laravel - 5.2
NPM - 3.9.5
Node - 6.2.2
Bower - 1.7.9
Semantic - 2.2.2

I am really out of ideas here I have tried all sorts of variations in path's, theme.config settings, everything I could think of.

*Edit* I should mention - I tried 'gulp watch' and then modified a .less file in /src/, the watcher picked up the change, then said it was building CSS (I did not see the Gulp message where it says which file it generated, only the msg 'Finished package uncompressed CSS'), and still no .css files in /dist/.  I even copied an older semantic.css into the /dist/ folder just to see, oddly enough, the script actually changes the modified time of semantic.css but nothing changed inside it. *Edit*

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange bug this one here. If at any point your Semantic UI build task does not compile CSS - try deleting your node_modules folder, and clearing any package.json you might have. Then slowly add back each node module you need, one at a time, each time checking your semantic 'gulp build' command inbetween.  We aren't 100% which module did it, but it was absolutely 100% something in the node_modules folder that was causing this bug.

I would start there if you encounter the same things. It cost us 2 days to figure this one out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1- Run the following command:

> npm install semantic-ui --save

2- Change current path to semantic folder using the following command:

> cd "semantic folder name" (for example cd semantic)

3- Run the following command:

> gulp build (if you did not install gulp, first install it using npm install -g gulp)

You can see the dist folder. Find semantic.min.js and semantic.min.css in the path below.

node_modules\semantic-ui\dist\semantic.min.css

semantic/dist/semantic.min.js

npm version: 6.4.1

gulp version: 3.9.1

semantic-ui version: 2.4.1